# x64 Windows 7 won't recognize my Sony DV cam DCR-TRV330 through Firewire

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, camera, firewire

I'm having issues using my Sony DV cam DCR-330 and windows 7 ultimate 64bit. I connect the DV Cam as I do it in another pcs (works flawless in windows windows xp 32 bit and another notebook with the same specs than mine but using windows vista x86) but windows doesn't get any "New hardware" in device manager

Is anyone having the same issue than I?

Comment: Have you verified the firewire port is working correctly in 7?  It ought to at least throw up the new device dialog if it saw something get plugged in.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to update the firewire driver for a legacy one!

1. Click Windows Start; type "device manager" into the Search box and
   select Device Manager (or launch Device Manager anyway you like)
2. Swivel open the "IEEE 1394 Bus host controllers" item
3. Right-click on your listed 1394 controller; select "Update Driver
   Software"
4. Click the "Browse my computer for driver software" button, followed
   by the "Let me pick from a list" button
5. Select the option that has "(Legacy)" at the end of the name; click
   Next and let the driver be installed
6. Close out of dialogs and retry capture

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue on W7 64 bit with a Sont DCR-48 (I think thats what it was) Camcorder - my only solution was to use USB - Sony was not supporting updated firewire drivers for older Camcorders -